# How do I mark a database query with a tag?

Tags: database

How do I mark a database query with a tag so that I may alter it via [hook_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7)? I get the concept, but does anyone know what the syntax is? A working example would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're struggling to find the documentation, the class is called [`SelectQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7), and you're looking for the [`addTag`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddTag/7) function.

```
$query = db_select('table', 't')->fields('t')->addTag('my_tag');
```

Then in your query alter:

```
function MYMODULE_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('my_tag')) {
    // Do something...
  }
}
```

Comment: Note, if the query has a tag, you can also use `hook_query_TAG_alter` e.g: `hook_query_my_tag_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query){}` similar to `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` for forms.